# Default page available over Internet using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

If user enter "https://apnabank.bank.com/Transfer/#/" URL then application working fine.But user dont know proper URL.If they give only  "https://apnabank.bank.com" then IBM http server error displaying.I have to show there dafault page "URL not found" like that.Please help me out.

Comment: It depends on your server, but can't you just bind the root URI to your /Transfer/#/ URI? Your server will respond a 302 redirect and job's done.

Comment: can we create default page for that when user enter only "https://apnabank.bank.com" .If ''Yes" then How??

Comment: I assume you use either ngRoute or ui-router? I think it will solve your problem there

Comment: I am using ngRoute but how to build code??

Answer (score 0):

See this

If you're using `ngRoute`, you can do like

```
$routeProvider
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Transfer/#/'
    });
```

If you're using `ui-router`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Transfer/#/');
```

Try above snippets if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**@Priyanka**, as you are using `ngRouter` i am giving you a sample example:

Assuming you have created `error.html` and other html templates.

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
        title: 'MyLogin',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/error', {
        title: 'Error Page',
        templateUrl: 'views/error.html',
        controller: 'errorController',//needed only if you want to do something in your error page.
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });


$routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/error'
    });
```

**Description**:
First `/login` is sample route usually be in any example like many others, it is just for example.

Then if user hits the url that is not handled by you, then you can redirect the user to your application's error page using `otherwise` like i handled in above code.`otherwise` then redirect all your non handled url's to the error page.

You just create an error.html somewhere in the project( Prefer in views directory) and give its path in the rout handler as in above example.

Hope This will help you. . .